# DNS config for roaming DC client laptop

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, laptop, roaming

We have a small office with one primary DC(192.168.1.6), one secondary DC(192.168.1.7) and 5 desktops connects thru LAN and two laptops thru Wifi. Both the DC's are local and can't be reached from the internet.

The internet router TP-Link(192.168.1.1) acts as the DHCP. A Netgear router configured as AP(192.168.1.2).

The clients get the ip address from the router.

DNS entries on all the clients point to 192.168.1.6 and 192.168.1.7.

Yesterday, one of our employee took the laptop to his home and connected to his home wifi. He cannot browse the internet because of the DNS issue. Once the DNS entries are removed on the laptop, he can browse the internet.

If I remove the DNS entries, the Group policy and the passwords are not getting updated. I have to manually change back the DNS once the laptop is back in the office.

How to avoid this issue, so the laptop can work in the office and home without changing the DNS?